# How to prevent an ui-router parameter override?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I'm currently working on a site with multiple sub-routes, and I'd like to create a simple url for user profiles, for example:

```
mydomain.com/someusername
```

But with my current UI-Router state configuration, it overrides all of my other urls, I guess because it considers the other routes as a parameter too.

```
.state('profile', {
  url: '/{username}',
  template: '...',
  controller: '...',
})
.state('other', {
  url: '/other',
  template: '...',
  controller: '...',
});
```

(Like in this example, the 'other' state will be considered as a parameter in profile state)

I've also tried subclassing it from a root state, but that didn't worked either. I can get around the problem by using an extra keyword in front of the usernames (eg: `mydomain.com/user/someusername`), but that's a bit more complicated from the user experience viewpoint.

Is there any way to do this like I'm trying to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of state definition is important.. just switch them

```
// more specific
.state('other', {
  url: '/other',
  template: '...',
  controller: '...',
})
// more general
.state('profile', {
  url: '/{username}',
  template: '...',
  controller: '...',
})
```

UI-Router is adding states into queue and later iterates it to find a match. So if general are last.. the more specific will be found properly

Comment: Ah okay, I just figured it out after posting the question :) Anyway, thanks very much, I'll accept the answer as soon as I can.